# How to Get MyLocation With Internet in Android?

Tags: android, gps, google-api

I can get My Location With GPS in android,But when I run my application in tablets, it's giving me an error Because GPS is unavailable and it's Error.
I use Google Api V2.
My code for GPS Location:

```
    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    Log.e("MAp","Map Created:");
    LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

Thanks.